# Execute jQuery function from asp:DataGrid ItemCommand

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp:DataGrid`, in this grid view an `asp:ButtonColumn`. When I click on delete action, I enter in the `"delete"` case switch. If the result is false, I'd like execute an jQuery function define in the .aspx page.

Is it possible to do this ?

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgList" InItemCommand="dgList_ItemCommand">
    <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

In the code behind :

```
protected void dgList_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "other_command":
            break;

        case "delete":
            bool myResult = new MyClass().GetTest();
                    //if myResult = false, I'd like execute a jquery function
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `execute a jquery function` means? Javascript is on client machine and you are on server side.

Comment: That's right. Is there a way to execute a javascript function depending of a codebehind result.

Comment: Are you using any update panel? or after this postback, whole page will be reloaded on client machine?

Comment: haaa no, I can try this solution. Thanks.

Comment: What just happened here? Will put it inside my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to begin at the client side using a ajax request to invoke the server side logic when you click the button. That way you can choose whether to continue on the client side or not.

You can move your delete code to a [page method](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) and invoke it from jQuery when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this, its a little obtrusive though.

Set myResult to a public bool depending on your result.

In the code behind:

```
case "delete":
            myResult = new MyClass().GetTest();
            break;
}
```

add:

```
protected bool myResult {get;set;}
```

In .aspx

```
<% if (myResult)
  { %>
    //Do Jquery here
<% } %>
```

However, if you want Javascript to react to a button press, you should attach a javascript function to the buttons onclick handler. For example, you can create a method for when the Datagrid has finshed its databinding, loop through the rows and attach a javascript function to that button.

Example:

```
protected void Datagrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Cast your Datagrid datasource to Dataset
   //Loop through the dataset
   //Cast the button (.Controls[1] is important to identify the button child control)


   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn =(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)row.Cells[x].Controls[1];
   btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "jquery_function_name()");
}
```